# Categorising dataframe into sig not sig based on pval

Tags: r, dataframe, geom-text

I realise this is an easy problem but I'm really struggling to resolve it.

I'm trying to create a new column within my dataframe which categories my rows into significant or not significant based on the pval results of this row, using the pval of less than 0.05 as the significance threshold.

I have my pval column , as a continuous variable and want to create a seocnd column which categories the pval into sig or not sig
as when plotting my data i wish to colour code in my geom aes the points via sig value

```
df%sigest <- c(....)
```

Comment: try `df$sig <- df$pval < 0.05`, which will create a boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` column, or `df$sig <- +df$pval < 0.05` which will create a 1/0 column